# Wordpress, The loop: display just 2 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

What's the best way to show just 2 posts in the loop?

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while (have_posts()):
    if ($i == 3)
    {
        break;
    }
    the_post();
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

Is there something more "beatiful" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=2');
```

before the loop.

Excerpt from the documentation page:

> query_posts() can be used to display different posts than those that would normally show up at a specific URL.

Comment: OMG, what a simple thing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// Printing post number 1 and 2
for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++){
    the_post();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
       post_here();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP_Query class, to avoid mixing the globals posts with your custom loop

```
$results = new WP_Query('posts_per_page');

if ($results->have-posts()) {
    while ($results->have_posts()) {
        $results->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}

unset($results);
```